# renderHighchart output not displaying in Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have some data which looks like:

```
# A tibble: 100 × 4
    price  habs  mts2 type    
    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
 1 338000     3    92 comprar 
 2 288000     4    79 comprar 
 3   3000     2    55 alquiler
 4    775     1    10 alquiler
 5 288000     4    76 comprar
```

In R I can plot the data using the following:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

highcharterPlotterFunction = function(TYPE){
  filteredDF = df %>%
    filter(type == TYPE)
  
  # formula = as.formula(y ~ x + I(x^2))
  
  lm.model <- augment(lm(price ~ mts2, data = filteredDF)) %>%
    mutate(
      .fitted = round(.fitted, 0)
    )
  
  highchart() %>%
    hc_add_series(data = lm.model,
                  type = "scatter",
                  hcaes(x = price, y = mts2, color = mts2),
                  showInLegend = FALSE,
                  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}')
    ) %>%
    hc_add_series(data = lm.model,
                  type = "line",
                  hcaes(x = .fitted, y = mts2),
                  color = "#0099F9",
                  showInLegend = FALSE,
                  dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE, format='{point.games}')
    ) %>%
    hc_title(text = str_to_title(TYPE))
}


c("comprar", "alquiler") %>%
  map(., ~highcharterPlotterFunction(.x)) %>%
  hw_grid(rowheight = 300, ncol = 1) %>%
  htmltools::browsable()
```

Which plots two highercharter graphics on top of each other. However, when I try to put it into a shiny App I do not get any output:

Shiny App:

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    p("plot goes below here"),
    highchartOutput('regressionPlots')
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  highcharterPlotterFunction = function(TYPE){
    filteredDF = reactive_regression_data() %>%
      filter(type == TYPE)

    # formula = as.formula(y ~ x + I(x^2))

    lm.model <- augment(lm(price ~ mts2, data = filteredDF)) %>%
      mutate(
        .fitted = round(.fitted, 0)
      )

    highchart() %>%
      hc_add_series(data = lm.model,
                    type = "scatter",
                    hcaes(x = price, y = mts2, color = mts2),
                    showInLegend = FALSE
      ) %>%
      hc_add_series(data = lm.model,
                    type = "line",
                    hcaes(x = .fitted, y = mts2),
                    color = "#0099F9",
                    showInLegend = FALSE
      ) %>%
      hc_title(text = str_to_title(TYPE))
  }

  reactive_regression_data = reactive(
    df %>%
      # filter(provincia == input$provinceSelect) %>%
      # filter(municipio == input$municipioSelect) %>%
      # filter(distrito == input$distritoSelect) %>%
      filter(price <= 1000000) %>%
      filter(mts2 <= 200)
  )

  output$regressionPlots <- renderHighchart({
    c("comprar", "alquiler") %>%
      map(., ~highcharterPlotterFunction(.x)) %>%
      hw_grid(rowheight = 300, ncol = 1) %>%
      htmltools::browsable()
  })
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(price = c(338000, 288000, 3000, 775, 288000, 230000, 
218000, 2900, 845000, 1250, 288000, 299000, 356000, 1500, 300000, 
1300, 1500, 288000, 405000, 715000, 225000, 294000, 790, 329000, 
320000, 1200, 1150, 715000, 415000, 715000, 295000, 1500, 348000, 
1100, 3000, 249000, 379000, 761000, 320000, 1995, 715000, 715000, 
229000, 1600, 389000, 330000, 212000, 415000, 288000, 950, 1850, 
365000, 1050, 1650, 1750, 350000, 288000, 715000, 1200, 990, 
260000, 234500, 1400, 288000, 1100, 1650, 348000, 332000, 288000, 
350000, 1350, 360000, 2800, 379000, 799000, 288000, 685000, 1700, 
890, 294000, 338000, 590000, 294000, 1050, 320000, 1990, 350000, 
1100, 365000, 365000, 294000, 299000, 288000, 490000, 229000, 
2095, 560000, 288000, 715000, 360000), habs = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 
3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 4, 3, 3, 
NA, NA, 3, NA, 3, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 4, 
2, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, NA, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 
3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2), mts2 = c(92, 79, 55, 
10, 76, 65, 57, 95, 121, 57, 76, 90, 70, 102, 74, 83, 88, 79, 
83, 109, 60, 75, 47, 75, 68, 70, 30, 109, 80, 109, 100, 75, 80, 
70, 135, 65, 95, 121, 68, 110, 109, 109, 63, 70, 100, 85, 54, 
100, 76, 45, 100, 94, 46, 71, 92, 87, 76, 109, 88, 68, 58, 65, 
104, 75, 75, 40, 80, 80, 76, 87, 75, 112, 95, 111, 135, 79, 88, 
115, 43, 75, 92, 145, 75, 46, 92, 47, 87, 75, 90, 63, 70, 85, 
76, 111, 60, 132, 140, 79, 109, 70), type = c("comprar", "comprar", 
"alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", 
"alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "alquiler", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "alquiler", 
"comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar", "comprar", "alquiler", "comprar", "comprar", 
"comprar", "comprar")), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You when you use `renderHighchart()`, the expression in the curly braces expects a return value of class `highchart`. However, when you combine multiple charts using `hw_grid()`, the return value is of class `shiny.tag`. Therefore, the output binding is not able to render the output and (silently) fails.

The simplest fix for this is to replace `renderHighchart()` with `renderUI()` and `highchartOutput()` with `uiOutput()`.

```r
shiny::shinyApp(
  shiny::fluidPage(
    shiny::uiOutput("chart")
  ),
  function(input, output, session) {
    output$chart <- shiny::renderUI({
      highcharter::hw_grid(
        highcharter::highcharts_demo(),
        highcharter::highcharts_demo()
      )
    })
  }
)
```

Annother approach would be to use two separate calls to `renderHighchart()/highchartOutput()` and combine the charts inside the UI. However, with this approach you won't be able to use `hw_grid()`

A third way, which is probably the most challenging yet the most flexible is to use the `highcharts.js` API to generate multiple axes as in the examples [here](https://jkunst.com/highcharter/reference/hc_add_yAxis.html). This way, the dual-axis chart will be represented as a single `highcharter` object which means that it can be passed to `renderHighchart()`.